# expected value E(X) of couples that sit together at one table.

Tags: probability, statistics

20 people, 10 couples, choose between 5 tables, 4 seats each. They choose arbitrarly. What is the E(X) of couples that happen to sit together at one table?

Answer (score 3):

Let $X_i$ be the random variable given by $1$ if couple number $i$ happen to sit together and $0$ otherwise. Then what you want is $E(X_1+\cdots+X_{10})$. Now use that expectation is linear and that the $X_i$, while not independent, are identically distributed.

Comment: I would just do: P(couples together)=P(K)=(10!/2!8!)/(20!/4!16!)= 45/4845. Then E(K)=n*p=20*(45/4845)=0.1857.

Comment: I would not do that @Jules . $\;$  Consider, for whichever table one partner sits, there are three of the nineteen remaining seats that are at the same table. $\;$  So $\mathsf E(X_i) = \boxed{\quad ?}$

Comment: 20!* (19!/3!16!) ? But that would be only for the first and second person who take seats.

Comment: @Jules I don't think you understood my point. I am saying that there is no need to even _consider_ such things as "if that other couple sits like this, and that couple sits like that, then that changes the probability for the current couple". Trying to figure out the probability that there are no couples seated together, and the probability that exactly three couples seated together and so on is difficult, long, and a _really_ roundabout way of calculating the expected number of pairs that are seated together. I am saying that it's enough to calculate $E(X_1)$ and multiply it by $10$.